# Kernel Panic on Ubuntu 20-04.01

Tags: kernel, vmware

I need to get to some files on this VM running Ubuntu 20.04.01. I dont mind having to make a new VM but the files are the culmination of months of work and I would like to be able to get them back by putting them on github or something.

After trying to boot both into ubuntu and the recovery mode through the advanced options I get this error screen.

When trying to use grub to boot into the system I get kernel panic again. If I can get into the command line on the system and use git to get the files out that would be great

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZamm.png)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 implies you've not applied *security fixes* to your system (*an fully-upgraded system will report as 20.04.4 currently*), but have you performed a `fsck` or file-system check (using whatever command is appropriate for your unstated file-system)? If issues relate to *file-system* issues, you'll find it boots normally post-fix..

Comment: Would I do that command in the grub command line as I cannot boot to a CLI? @guiverc

Comment: download a Ubuntu install ISO and set it to boot from, set your VM HDD as secondary disk, boot (in "Try Ubuntu"-mode), then mount the HDD and see if you can access files...

Comment: I'd perform file-system checks using *live* media; as that avoids a *busy* drive, which makes the process so much easier.  Grub is a boot loader, so only has limited boot commands, it's running before the system is booted; so only its few commands are available.

Comment: Just so that I fully understand this (sorry i am not much of a sys admin) I need to make a new VM and set it to boot from the ubuntu iso and then during the creation process I use the vmdk of the original VM as an extra disk?

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help, I was able to get the files back using this method. I really appreciate your help